# Image isn't displaying

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a div property inside a form where I want to display an image.
But I can't manage to fix it. I get an HTTP ERROR 404.

My solution tree looks like:
MyProject
--Controllers
--img
----Logo.jpg
--Models
--Views
----Home
------Login.cshtml

Part of Login.cshtml, where I have the img property.

```
<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
    <img src="~/img/Logo.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm a doing wrong?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: have you tried `../img/Logo.jpg` instead of `~/img/Logo.jpg` ? you might have a way in asp.net to define a directory for static resources such as images, stylesheets etc... (but for sure `~` is the `home` directory of your user, which is not `MyProject`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using razor, you could write something like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/img/Logo.jpg")">
```

Comment: This works. But I solve my problem by adding a virtual path <virtualDirectory path="/img" physicalPath="path\to\img" /> at applicationhost.config and use the <img src="~/img/Logo.jpg">.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use tilde (~) client side in an `img` tag as it will not be able to resolve the root directory.

You need to use relative path from the page:

```
<img src="../img/Logo.jpg">
```

If you want to use tilde you will need to use server side markup.

Comment: I had try that and didn't help.

Comment: You will need to use the correct path to your image folder. I was gussing. What is your Resolved URL? Another guess here. Try `../../img/Logo.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

`~`is assigned to your user root directory, like this `/Users/myself`.

User `rootoftheproject/path/to/img/Logo.jpg` instead of `~/img/Logo.jpg`